# How to insert rows if not exist in Liquibase in Yaml format

Tags: postgresql, yaml, liquibase

I have a ***Table A:***

```
A
--------------
id  |  name  |
```

How to insert rows in this table if row with such NAME already exists.

I need to do it in Liquibase in Yaml format

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.h
tml) format you listed in the tags. You seem to have neither format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquibase changesets can be executed on a given [precondition](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html). In your case you could run a sqlCheck:

```yaml
- changeSet:
    id: 1
    author: me
    preConditions:
      - onFail: MARK_RAN
      - sqlCheck:
          expectedResult: 0
          sql: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE name = 'John'
    changes:
     - insert:
         tableName: person
         columns:
           - column:
               name: id
               value: 2
           - column:
               name: name
               value: John
```